# Amazon Web Services Beanstalk, git aws.push appears to push, but doesn't change anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I've seen a number of similar issues, but with no actual solution. Following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html, I created a sample app without issue. However, I modified a few files, including the gemfile, ran bundle install, ran `git add . && git commit -m "commit gemfile change"`

Then, I ran git aws.push, received the following:

```
> c:\Users\mmoore\Documents\rubyapps\visitdaysaws>git aws.push Counting
> objects: 8, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing
> objects: 100% (5/5), done. Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 653 bytes,
> done. Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: To
> https://[secureurl]
>    091700..00005f  39eed5f98abacccccccccsaadeeeffa044354b740 -> master


c:\Users\mmatches\Documents\rubyapps\appaws>"c:\Ruby193\AWS-ElasticBeanstalk
-CLI-2.3.1\eb\windows\eb" status --verbose
Retrieving status of environment "appaws-env".
URL     : appaws-env-dxf4aghrer.elasticbeanstalk.com
Status  : Ready
Health  : Green
Environment Name:       appaws-env
Environment ID:         e-123abz4rpw
Solution Stack:         64bit Amazon Linux running Ruby 1.9.3
Version Label:          git-39eed5f98abacccccccccsaadeeeffa044354b740-1363313513
78
Date Created:           2013-03-15 13:48:56
Date Updated:           2013-03-15 16:34:00
Description:            None

RDS Database: AWSEBRDSDatabase | aa1adfga3tfa2a.cadfef60egmm.us-east-1.rds.amaz
onaws.com:3306
Database Engine:        mysql 5.5.27
Allocated Storage:      5
Instance Class:         db.t1.micro
Multi AZ:               False
Master Username:        ebroot
Creation Time:          2013-03-15 13:54:20
DB Instance Status:     available
```

Despite this, I still receive the generic Welcome message:
[image: AWS Generic Welcome Page]

I've checked the size of my git repo and it's larger than the default app, but only 6.5 MiB. I've also tried pasting in core files, no change. I'm open to any ideas at all.

**Update**

Ran the suggested remove file, still received the general page, but when navigating to index.html (which theoretically is not there), you can see the application load or attempt to load via an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example app, the welcome message is within `public/index.html`.

That means, as long as you don't remove that static file, your homepage will keep displaying the welcome message.

Any changes other than `git rm public/index.html` will not make the message disappear.

Comment: Thank you so much for ending the nightmare of my noobish mistake.