# Rails AWS: Main Welcome Page Won't Go Away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a basic Rails app running with postgresql. Locally it's happy as a clam. I've run eb init, eb start, and eb status which returns the url, status ready, and health green. Locally, my changes are showing up on my rails app (nothing intense, just a root somewhere that isn't the beanstalk welcome screen). When I git aws.push it pushes to the correct environment name, happily pressed and compresses objects, ends with "remote to" + long string + "HEAD -> master (forced update)".

I wait until git "eb status" is green again (it says updating initially, so it's clearly going to the right place) and then go to the url specified...and the beanstalk greeting remains.

*(No longer relevant; seems this solution only applies for earlier versions of rails; keeping it for comment clarity) This person ([Amazon Web Services Beanstalk, git aws.push appears to push, but doesn't change anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442491/amazon-web-services-beanstalk-git-aws-push-appears-to-push-but-doesnt-change)) had a similar issue, but when I type "git rm public/index.html" I get "fatal: pathspec 'public/index.html' did not match any files".*

I'm using Rails 4.0.1. Any ideas?

Edit:

I think the problem may be related to not using a RDS; when I used one, this issue did not exist. But on this app I'm trying to run a local Postgresql similar to how I'd do it on Heroku...

Edit:

My route file

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :users

   root "users#show"
end
```

Edit:

Looking at the EC2, in the recent activity it states

```
Instance: i-9ebf03b0 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on      instance. 
Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed.
```

Looking in the logs I see this:

```
Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb 
    checking for pg_config... no
    No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
    checking for libpq-fe.h... no
    Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You    
    may need configuration options
```

Researching and trying a variety of things given the above; just wanted to keep helpful, inquiring people updated :)

Comment: public/index.html has been removed bydefault in rails 4.0,so this file will not be available.

Comment: update the qsn with your config/routes file

Comment: could you be a bit more specific with the qsn and config/routes file? I don't know what qsn stands for...

Comment: Can update your question with config/routes file from your rails application

Comment: Are you working on the correct branch? Make sure that you're on the correct branch. Then merge that correct branch with the master. Then see if you still receive "fatal: pathspec 'public/index.html' did not match any files" error.

Comment: @SackboyB are you sure branch is of any concern in this issue

Comment: @GhostRider - Well, the git error Morgan received is usually a branch concern for me. But I might be wrong.

Comment: The solution which is being referred in question points to a application which uses rails 3.2.4. This version creates public/index.html
on creating the rails application. While Morgan is using rails 4 which will not contain public/index.html file.

Comment: Added the config/routes file; it's really straightforward. I've done nothing on this thing but try to get a database up and working and the rails functional on an instance. The db is pg and is on a EC2 instance as well; that is working fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

If I go to the EC2 instance handling the Rails App and type the following it fixes the problem.

sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs postgresql-libs

In retrospect I wish I had entered the above one by one to see WHICH exactly was fixing the problem, but there it is all the same.

Comment: I'll offer a little elucidation from my own experience with Rails+Beanstalk. The beanstalk instance by default tries to "bundle install" before adding the instance to the load balancer. The mysql2 gem installs without a problem, which means that the instance Amazon provides already has the dependencies for compiling that gem, but (inferring from Morgan's error message) it does not have Postgres headers/libs. It certainly doesn't run a Postgres server by default, but that would have been a separate error.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to want to add that to a config so that it scales:

```
$ cat .ebextensions/postgres.config
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```